# Upgrading ffmpeg from v4.4.3 to v6 with apt in 22.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, ffmpeg

I'm trying to install the latest ffmpeg version on Ubuntu 22.04.
Using [ubuntuhandbook's guide](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/03/ffmpeg-6-0-released-how-to-install-in-ubuntu-22-04-20-04/) proved no success.
The commands in the guide are:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg6
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

However I'm still stuck on v4.4.3. Restarting the computer has no effect.
I've also tried [linuxcapable's guide](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-6-on-ubuntu-linux/) without it working either.
The guide recommends these commands:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install dirmngr ca-certificates software-properties-common apt-transport-https
sudo gpg --list-keys
sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/rob-savoury.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E996735927E427A733BB653E374C7797FB006459
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/rob-savoury.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ffmpeg-rob-savoury.list
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/rob-savoury.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/ffmpeg6/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ffmpeg-rob-savoury.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

I know it's possible to download a static build of ffmpeg, but I'd greatly prefer to do it via apt if possible. It's a fairly clean install of Ubuntu too, my apt source list contains these repositories.

1. archive_uri-https_packages_microsoft_com_repos_vscode-jammy.list
2. savoury1-ubuntu-ffmpeg6-jammy.list
3. deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
4. savoury1-ubuntu-graphics-jammy.list
5. microsoft-prod.list
6. savoury1-ubuntu-multimedia-jammy.list
7. savoury1-ubuntu-ffmpeg4-jammy.list
8. vscode.list

Output from `apt policy ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg:
  Installed: 7:4.4.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav5
  Candidate: 7:6.0-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav1.1
  Version table:
     7:6.0-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav1.1 500
        500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/ffmpeg6/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7:4.4.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav5 500
        500 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/savoury1/ffmpeg4/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7:4.4.2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 500
        500 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
     7:4.4.1-3ubuntu5 500
        500 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please provide output of the following in your question: `apt policy ffmpeg`. Maybe you have to install a specific version from the PPA. Also, did you try and run `sudo apt full-upgrade` after you installed `ffmpeg`?

Comment: @ Artur Meinild Edited, and yes I ran full-upgrade while ffmpeg 4 was already installed.

Comment: The FFmpeg trac will guide you to install the latest git FFmpeg with copy and paste compiling instructions: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the specific version you want, like this:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg=7:6.0-0ubuntu1~22.04.sav1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are venturing outside of the standard software of Ubuntu anyway, then there is no objection whatsoever to download and run the static binary. Do that, and you will be using the newer version.

Place it in `/usr/local/bin`. That way, it is in the path and can be run as such on the terminal. Placed in that location, it will override any system installed executable with the same name. Secondly, placing it there you are not interfering with directories managed by the APT system.

If you insist on using the PPA, then your story - which does not indicate something erroneous in the procedure - suggests that that PPA also may be containing the same version as the one supplied by the Ubuntu software center.